# Color mapping not working with plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

I have a data frame like this

```
df1 <- data.frame("time" = 1:10, A1 = rnorm(10), B1 = rnorm(10), C1 = rnorm(10), D1 = rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame("time" = 1:5, A2 = rnorm(5), B2 = rnorm(5),  C2 = rnorm(5), D2 = rnorm(5))
```

I want to plot df1 with "time" on x axis and all other variables on the y axis. Similarly, I want to plot df2 with "time" on x axis and all other variables on the y axis. In this case,
I want the lines to be "dot" and markers to be hollow circles.
I specified the following colors to be used

```
my_colors <- c(             ## add the standard plotly colors
  'red',  
  'blue',  
  'green',  
  'yellow'
)
```

Here is the plotly code I tried

```
longDF1 <- melt(df1, id.vars = "time")
longDF2 <- melt(df2, id.vars = "time")
  
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data = longDF1, x = ~time, y = ~value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers', color = ~variable,
            line = list(color = my_colors, dash = 'solid'),
            marker = list(color = my_colors, symbol = 'circle')) %>% 
  add_trace(data = longDF2, x = ~time, y = ~value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers', color = ~variable,
            line = list(color = my_colors, dash = 'dot'),
            marker = list(color = my_colors, symbol = 'circle-open'))
```

The colors dont seem to be added to the plots. Instead, plotly generates its own colors. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your desired colors drop the `color` attribute from the `line` and `marker` specs and instead pass your color vector to the `colors` attribute, where it is sufficient to pass it to the first trace only or directly inside `plot_ly()` as I do below. Additionally, as you you have eight different categories duplicate your color vector, i.e. use `colors = c(my_colors, my_colors)`.

```r
library(plotly)

set.seed(123)

plot_ly(colors = c(my_colors, my_colors)) %>%
  add_trace(
    data = longDF1, x = ~time, y = ~value, type = "scatter", mode = "lines+markers", color = ~variable,
    line = list(dash = "solid"),
    marker = list(symbol = "circle")
  ) %>%
  add_trace(
    data = longDF2, x = ~time, y = ~value, type = "scatter", mode = "lines+markers", color = ~variable,
    line = list(dash = "dot"),
    marker = list(symbol = "circle-open")
  )
```

[image]